# Images under Bootstrap Card component are in wrong ratio

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, frontend, bootstrap-5

So I'm working on a personal project of making an ecommerce cart. I was trying to add some images to the card components for the products part. I'm not sure how should I make sure how to make them fit exactly in the image section of the Bootstrap card component. I'll put in some screenshots so the problem is clearer.

This is how the code looks like right now -

```
<Card>
    <Card.Img variant="top" src={imgUrl} height="200px" style={{ objectFit: 'cover' }} />
</Card>
```

So, I tried a few different things, like changing objectFit to cover, and adding maxHeight, maxWidth and so on. But it never allowed images to fit in properly.
First image with objectFit as Contain -
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjwLs.jpg)
Second with objectFit as cover -
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQvFk.jpg)

Now, since the objects will be looped, and I can't do it for each image individually, how should I go about correcting this. Should I have like a rule for the pictures that I choose, like particular dimensions or backgrounds, and is that how it's normally done for most ecommerce websites, or like should I change certain things about bootstrap card components(pretty sure it's just a css issue?).

Also, I'm following a tutorial, which is a little old, would appreciate help about if bootstrap is old or if it has changed, or should I do it certain other way.

Comment: do you know css aspect ratio? 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio

Comment: @Re9iNee i tried using it, but couldn't figure it out from it either.